# How to get text inbetween brackets

Tags: c#

So I am trying to get the text in between brackets in C#.

I want to get `SYSTEM` from `[SYSTEM]: Welcome`.

(All known instances)

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by all known instances, but you can use

```
// to extract a single substring split should do the job
var input = "[SYSTEM]: Welcome";
var output = input.Split('[', ']')[1];

// output will be SYSTEM

// for multiple occurances you can use regular expression
var inputTwo = "[SYSTEM]: Welcome [other]";

var pattern = @"\[([^\[\]]+)\]";

var outputs = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputTwo, pattern))
{
    outputs.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}

//  outputs will be ["SYSTEM", "other"]
```

Comment: Very slow if there is a lot of brackets.